# ERROR: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 when compiling a Shared library that uses MPI

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, mpi

I want to compile a library that uses mpi. I am running into an error when compiling the very simple example presented below:

```
#ifndef __MPIWRAPPER_HPP__
#define __MPIWRAPPER_HPP__

#include <ostream>
#include "mpi.h"

class MPIWrapper
{
   public:

   MPIWrapper(MPI_Comm comunicator);
   void sayhello();

   private:

   int rank_;
   int n_processes_;
};
#endif
```

The source file

```
#include "MPIWrapper.hpp"
#include "mpi.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

MPIWrapper::MPIWrapper(MPI_Comm comunicator){
   MPI_Comm_size(comunicator, &n_processes_);   
   MPI_Comm_rank(comunicator, &rank_); 
}

void MPIWrapper::sayhello(){
   std::cout << "Hello, World! " << "I am process "<< rank_ <<" of "<< 
   n_processes_<<"\n";
}
```

And the CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
PROJECT( mpi_wrapper )
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE release)

find_package(MPI REQUIRED)

ADD_LIBRARY( wrapper SHARED MPIWrapper.cpp)
TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( wrapper PUBLIC "${MPI_CXX_INCLUDE_PATH}")
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( wrapper "${MPI_CXX_LIBRARIES_PATH}")
```

When I try to compile the code I get an error with the linker. I wonder if the problem is related to my compiler or if I am missing any property that I need to specify. I am running cmake 3.2 on MAC OS X with gnu compiler 4.9 and mpich-3.2

and the output from make

```
Scanning dependencies of target wrapper
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/wrapper.dir/MPIWrapper.cpp.o
Linking CXX shared library libwrapper.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_MPI_Comm_rank", referenced from:
      MPIWrapper::MPIWrapper(int) in MPIWrapper.cpp.o
      MPIWrapper::MPIWrapper(int) in MPIWrapper.cpp.o
  "_MPI_Comm_size", referenced from:
      MPIWrapper::MPIWrapper(int) in MPIWrapper.cpp.o
      MPIWrapper::MPIWrapper(int) in MPIWrapper.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [libwrapper.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/wrapper.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I appreciate any help. 
Thanks

Comment: Where did you get `MPI_CXX_LIBRARIES_PATH` from? Shouldn't it be `${MPI_LIBRARIES}` instead?

Comment: actually `MPI_CXX_LIBRARIES`.

Comment: Thanks I found the problem. First I had the wrong name for the library variable. Second I have more than one mpi installation in my machine. After setting properly the environment variables I got the library to compile and link.  CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH, CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH